Issues with connect.sid Cookie Disappearing in Production After Enabling CORS
I'm experiencing an issue with the connect.sid cookie in my Express application. Everything works perfectly in my local environment, where the cookie is created and persists as expected. However, once I deploy to production and enable CORS, the connect.sid cookie seems to disappear quickly after it's generated.
Environment Details:
Framework: Express.js
Session Middleware: express-session
onst corsOptions = {
  origin: ['https://voiceblogify.netlify.app'], 
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH'],
  credentials: true,
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'], 
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET_SESSION_KEY,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // 1 day
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production', 
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite:  'None', domain: '.voiceblogify.netlify.app'
  },
}));


[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/6JgEmdBM.png)

live link https://voiceblogify.netlify.app/

Issue Description:
Local Environment: The connect.sid cookie is created and persists without any issues.
Production Environment: After enabling CORS and setting the secure flag to true, the connect.sid cookie is generated but disappears shortly after.
Additional Observations:
The server is behind a proxy, so I set app.set('trust proxy', 1);.
I've added logging to monitor the cookies and session state on each request.
Questions:
https://voiceblogify.netlify.app/
useEffect(() => {

        async function checkAuth() {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('https://voiceblogify-backend.onrender.com/status', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    credentials: 'include'
                });
                const data = await response.json();

                console.log(data)


                if (data.authenticated) {
                    setIsAuthenticated(true);
                    setUser({
                        name: data.name,
                        profilepicurl: data.profilepic,
                        userId: data.id
                    });
                    setPaidMember(false);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error checking auth:', error);
            }
        }

        checkAuth();
    }, []);

calling from fronted side
Why is the connect.sid cookie being destroyed quickly in production?
Are there any specific configurations I might be missing related to CORS or session management?
Could there be any issues with the way the proxy is configured that might affect cookie transmission?

If your backend is on https://voiceblogify-backend.onrender.com, the Domain attribute of a cookie it sets cannot be voiceblogify.netlify.app. Browsers silently reject such attempts. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#domaindomain-value

after removing the domain ,the problem is persistent
